# Correct use of weeks'

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Consider the following statement:

> I have four assessments due in a weeks' time.

Here, the four assessments are due in one week. I am unsure if the apostrophe is placed correctly, i.e. is weeks' or week's more appropriate in this instance.

Comment: *a week* is singular. It should be *in a week's time*. If there were two or more *weeks* then it would be *in two weeks' time*.

Comment: Hmmm... Can a week own something? I would say "due in a week."  Or possibly "within a week." I would not use "weeks time."  Unless there was a person called Week.

Comment: @puppetsock - a minute's, an hour's, a day's, a week's time (etc) are all perfectly normal and acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An apostrophe showing possession always goes after the thing that is doing the possessing. You might not think of a week as possessing time, but that is actually what it's saying - the amount of time that is contained within a week. It often helps to turn the phrase around in your head to make it clearer:

> The girl's toys: the toys belonging to the girl
>   The girls' toys: the toys belonging to the girls